# Paypal IPN over HTTP not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to connect to the PayPal IPN over regular HTTP for testing purposes and I cant get my PHP script to connect. I dont have an ssl cert installed so any attempt at using ssl with port 443 fails. Here is my attempt to connect over HTTP:

$fp = fsockopen('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

The response ends up coming back like so:

HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
Server: BigIP
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

I have read that with the new SHA-256 requirements, PayPal will still allow connection over http so am I doing something wrong or is my information incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has stopped acceptting HTTP 1.0 on IPN endpoint, you should change HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1

Comment: I would also encourage https since this can contain customer information.